# How do I prevent the Django admin delete confirmation view to display all the objects to be deleted?

Tags: python, django

I have a object that has several thousand related objects. How can I make the confirmation view in the Django administration only display the Yes/No buttons without the list of all the objects to be deleted.

The problem is that displaying the whole list of objects takes way too much time. I am using Django 3.0.3.

Comment: You might need to override `delete_confirmation.html` template. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/

Comment: @Shinratensei I tried this but it does not work for some reason.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer on the link you posted. The accepted answer was not working but the other one was.